# Permissions with Zend Server CE, daemon:daemon does not have enough permissions on OSX

Tags: php, macos, webserver, file-permissions, directory-permissions

Strangely enough the server can't resize images any more because it doesn't have enough write permissions. When I check the permissions of the directory I want to write my resized images to I see:

username staff

After excecuting echo exec('whoami');
and checking the httpd.conf I saw the user and group for the server was daemon:daemon (this seems to be the default for Zend Server CE on an OSX installation). What should I do so I have enough permissions again. Should I chown my directory to daemon:daemon (what isn't working). Should I change the user of the server or something else?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there's no point in touching the web server user - it makes sense for Apache to run as a dedicated user and not have access to all your personal files.

The best way to solve this in my experience is to change the file's group to `daemon` and make it group-writable, but keep you the owner of the file so you can edit / delete it as well. On OS X terminal this is done by:

```
$ sudo chgrp daemon <file>
$ sudo chmod 664 <file>
```

Obviously replace `<file>` with the name of the file you want to give access to.

Another easy way out is to run `chmod 666` on the file - make it world writable, but this is not recommended if you care about security in any way (might be ok on your own development environment but never in production or a shared environment).

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on if you are using this in production in the wild or in private. If it were me, I would simply chown the directory for use with the server only. If you give access to that group, you will open up access to many more things.